# Multiple joins with MySQL, getting unexpected results

Tags: mysql

I am trying to join 3 tables but it looks like I am doing something wrong. Also I am not sure if INNER JOIN is a good idea here because there might be some missing corresponding rows in the other tables, but I would still like them to show up as NULL, then maybe LEFT JOIN would be better, but again, I'm doing something wrong.

A quick summary of the table responses:

```
SELECT geonameid, name, iso_alpha2, admin1_code
FROM maxmind_cities1000
WHERE name LIKE 'tron%' LIMIT 20;

+-----------+------------------------+------------+-------------+
| geonameid | name                   | iso_alpha2 | admin1_code |
+-----------+------------------------+------------+-------------+
|   1605268 | Tron                   | TH         | 10          |
|   8949073 | Tronca                 | IT         | 03          |
|   3107444 | Tronchón               | ES         | 52          |
|   8859151 | Tronconal              | MX         | 21          |
|   2821000 | Tröndel                | DE         | 10          |
|   3133880 | Trondheim              | NO         | 16          |
|   1252408 | Trongsa                | BT         | 21          |
|   2667264 | Trönninge              | SE         | 06          |
|   6535739 | Trontano               | IT         | 12          |
|   2971582 | Tronville-en-Barrois   | FR         | B2          |
|   3165134 | Tronzano Lago Maggiore | IT         | 09          |
|   3165133 | Tronzano Vercellese    | IT         | 12          |
+-----------+------------------------+------------+-------------+

SELECT iso_alpha2, name
FROM maxmind_countryinfo
WHERE iso_alpha2 = 'NO';

+------------+--------+
| iso_alpha2 | name   |
+------------+--------+
| NO         | Norway |
+------------+--------+

SELECT code, name_local
FROM maxmind_admin1_codes_ascii
WHERE code = 'NO.16';

+-------+-----------------+
| code  | name_local      |
+-------+-----------------+
| NO.16 | Sør-Trøndelag   |
+-------+-----------------+
```

So basically I am trying to join these three tables with this query, I have made a special case and said `ON admin1.code = 'NO.16'`

```
SELECT
    city.geonameid as city_id,
    city.name as city_name,
    country.name as country_name,
    admin1.name_local as admin1_code
FROM maxmind_cities1000 as city
    INNER JOIN maxmind_countryinfo as country
        ON city.iso_alpha2 = country.iso_alpha2
    INNER JOIN maxmind_admin1_codes_ascii as admin1
        ON admin1.code = 'NO.16'
WHERE city.name LIKE 'tron%' LIMIT 20;
```

but it gives me all the rows anyways instead of just Trondheim norway, so I am doing something wrong here. I tried switching to LEFT JOIN but get the same result set. I would like the city to show up in the result set even if there are no matching rows in maxmind_admin1_codes_ascii table, the admin code has the format iso_aplha2 '.' admin1_code

```
+---------+------------------------+--------------+-----------------+
| city_id | city_name              | country_name | admin1_code     |
+---------+------------------------+--------------+-----------------+
| 1605268 | Tron                   | Thailand     | Sør-Trøndelag   |
| 8949073 | Tronca                 | Italy        | Sør-Trøndelag   |
| 3107444 | Tronchón               | Spain        | Sør-Trøndelag   |
| 8859151 | Tronconal              | Mexico       | Sør-Trøndelag   |
| 2821000 | Tröndel                | Germany      | Sør-Trøndelag   |
| 3133880 | Trondheim              | Norway       | Sør-Trøndelag   |
| 1252408 | Trongsa                | Bhutan       | Sør-Trøndelag   |
| 2667264 | Trönninge              | Sweden       | Sør-Trøndelag   |
| 6535739 | Trontano               | Italy        | Sør-Trøndelag   |
| 2971582 | Tronville-en-Barrois   | France       | Sør-Trøndelag   |
| 3165134 | Tronzano Lago Maggiore | Italy        | Sør-Trøndelag   |
| 3165133 | Tronzano Vercellese    | Italy        | Sør-Trøndelag   |
+---------+------------------------+--------------+-----------------+
```

This is my end result query but still don't understand why it gives me all results when I just want the special case 'NO.16'. And how should I structure my query if I want the cities to show regardless of there are no matching rows in the maxmind_admin1_codes_ascii table? This is what I have so far

```
SELECT
    city.geonameid as city_id,
    city.name as city_name,
    country.name as country_name,
    admin1.name_local as admin1_code
FROM maxmind_cities1000 as city
    INNER JOIN maxmind_countryinfo as country
        ON city.iso_alpha2 = country.iso_alpha2
    INNER JOIN maxmind_admin1_codes_ascii as admin1
        ON admin1.code = CONCAT(city.iso_alpha2, '.', city.admin1_code)
WHERE city.name LIKE 'tron%' LIMIT 20;

+---------+------------------------+--------------+--------------------+
| city_id | city_name              | country_name | admin1_code        |
+---------+------------------------+--------------+--------------------+
| 1605268 | Tron                   | Thailand     | Uttaradit          |
| 8949073 | Tronca                 | Italy        | Calabria           |
| 3107444 | Tronchón               | Spain        | Aragon             |
| 8859151 | Tronconal              | Mexico       | Puebla             |
| 2821000 | Tröndel                | Germany      | Schleswig-Holstein |
| 3133880 | Trondheim              | Norway       | Sør-Trøndelag      |
| 1252408 | Trongsa                | Bhutan       | Tongsa             |
| 2667264 | Trönninge              | Sweden       | Halland            |
| 6535739 | Trontano               | Italy        | Piedmont           |
| 2971582 | Tronville-en-Barrois   | France       | Lorraine           |
| 3165134 | Tronzano Lago Maggiore | Italy        | Lombardy           |
| 3165133 | Tronzano Vercellese    | Italy        | Piedmont           |
+---------+------------------------+--------------+--------------------+
```

This gives the result I want, but I don't think I am doing it right because the result was unexpected with the special case of 'NO.16'. Hope someone can help out!

Comment: The `ON` clause should contain the joining condition that says how the two tables relate to each other. If you don't do that, you get a full cross-product insetead of just the related rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not totally sure if I understand what you are trying to do - but maybe this?

```
SELECT
    city.geonameid as city_id,
    city.name as city_name,
    country.name as country_name,
    admin1.name_local as admin1_code
FROM maxmind_cities1000 as city
    INNER JOIN maxmind_countryinfo as country
        ON city.iso_alpha2 = country.iso_alpha2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN maxmind_admin1_codes_ascii as admin1
        ON admin1.code = CONCAT(city.iso_alpha2, '.', city.admin1_code)
        AND admin1.code = 'NO.16'
WHERE city.name LIKE 'tron%' LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: thank you left outer join was what I should have used, now when I delete NO.16 from the admin table the city still shows up but as NULL. Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    city.geonameid as city_id,
    city.name as city_name,
    country.name as country_name,
    admin1.name_local as admin1_code
FROM maxmind_cities1000 as city
    INNER JOIN maxmind_countryinfo as country
        ON city.iso_alpha2 = country.iso_alpha2
    INNER JOIN maxmind_admin1_codes_ascii as admin1
        ON admin1.code = city.admin1_code
WHERE city.name LIKE 'tron%' LIMIT 20 AND city.admin1_code = 'NO.16';
```